# DNS Records: Multiple CNAME entries to the same value

Tags: url, dns, routes, http-proxy, cname

I'm stuck with a rather basic problem: I want a website be reachable at the domains **get**.mysite.com and **www**.mysite.com. Therefore, I set up my DNS records as such:

```
Host Name        Value
get.mysite.com   sitebuilder.com
www.mysite.com   sitebuilder.com
```

While the "www" part works, I "get" is unreachable. What am I missing here? Might it not be possible to have multiple hosts connect to the same value?

Looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Please check web server host setup. Perhaps it is listing [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) domain, in which case you need to add get.mysite.com there.